# Get $form_state backup and migrate filter extended class

Tags: hooks, forms

I have form altered the backup and migrate quick backup screen (admin/config/system/backup_migrate) and added a text field. I'd like to use the value of the field to create a new node just before the backup is done. I found [a way to "hook" backup and migrate](https://www.drupal.org/node/1539486) just before it performs a backup, which is great. However, I need to get $form_state['values']['my_value'] and pass that to my function that creates a new node. I can't figure out how to get that passed to the pre_backup() inside the extended class backup_migrate_filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, I get you altered the form built from the following function.

```
/**
 * The quick backup form.
 */
function backup_migrate_ui_manual_quick_backup_form($form, &$form_state, $inline = TRUE) {
  backup_migrate_include('profiles', 'destinations', 'sources');
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'backup_migrate') .'/backup_migrate.js');

  $form = array();

  // Theme the form if we want it inline.
  if ($inline) {
    $form['#theme'] = 'backup_migrate_ui_manual_quick_backup_form_inline';
  }

  $form['quickbackup'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    "#title" => t("Quick Backup"),
    "#collapsible" => FALSE,
    "#collapsed" => FALSE,
    "#tree" => FALSE,
  );

  $form['quickbackup']['source_id'] = _backup_migrate_get_source_pulldown(variable_get('backup_migrate_source_id', NULL));

  $form['quickbackup']['destination'] = _backup_migrate_get_destination_pulldown('manual backup', variable_get('backup_migrate_destination_id', 'download'), variable_get('backup_migrate_copy_destination_id', ''));

  $profile_options = _backup_migrate_get_profile_form_item_options();
  $form['quickbackup']['profile_id'] = array(
    "#type" => "select",
    "#title" => t("Settings Profile"),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('backup_migrate_profile_id', NULL),
    "#options" => $profile_options,
  );

  $form['quickbackup']['description_enabled'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    "#title" => t("Add a note to the backup"),
  );
  $form['quickbackup']['description'] = array(
    '#type' => 'backup_migrate_dependent',
    '#dependencies' => array(
      'description_enabled' => TRUE,
    ),
  );

  $form['quickbackup']['description']['description'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    "#title" => t("Note"),
    '#description' => t('This note will be saved with the backup file and shown on the listing page.'),
  );

  $form['advanced'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => '<div class="clearblock backup-migrate-footer-message">' . t('For more backup options, try the <a href="!advancedurl">advanced backup page</a>.', array('!advancedurl' => url(BACKUP_MIGRATE_MENU_PATH . '/export/advanced'))) . '</div>',
  );

  $form['quickbackup']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Backup now'),
    '#weight' => 1,
  );

  $form['#validate'] = array('backup_migrate_ui_manual_quick_backup_form_validate');
  $form['#submit'] = array('backup_migrate_ui_manual_quick_backup_form_submit');

  return _backup_migrate_ui_action_form($form, $form_state, 'backup');
}
```

The only way to pass a value submitted in a form to a hook is to save it into a persistent variable, exactly in the same way a submission handler does.

```
/**
 * Submit the quick backup form.
 */
function backup_migrate_ui_manual_quick_backup_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  backup_migrate_include('profiles', 'destinations');
  if (user_access('perform backup') && !empty($form_state['values']['settings'])) {
    // Save the settings for next time.
    variable_set("backup_migrate_source_id", $form_state['values']['source_id']);
    variable_set("backup_migrate_destination_id", $form_state['values']['destination_id']);
    variable_set("backup_migrate_copy_destination_id", $form_state['values']['copy_destination_id']);
    variable_set("backup_migrate_profile_id", $form_state['values']['profile_id']);

    // Do the backup.
    backup_migrate_ui_manual_backup_perform($form_state['values']['settings']);
  }
  $form_state['redirect'] = BACKUP_MIGRATE_MENU_PATH;
}
```

Your `hook_form_alter()` implementation needs to do two things:

- Add the form element, as you already did
- Add a submission handler to `$form['#submit']` (`$form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_submission_callback';`)

Comment: Most excellent! I should have mentioned that I did end getting the clues I needed from a friend and I added my function to the submit handler. Thank you for replying! An upvote for you, sir.